# Discord JS bot crashing after sending a dm message

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

I want my bot to send a dm to someone executing the command `!RHelp`.
For that I wrote this code:

```
if (message.content.startsWith('!RHelp')){
        client.users.fetch('<User ID>').then((user) => user.send('Hello World'));
        message.reply('I just sent you a DM');}
```

The bot is correctly executing the code but after sending the message he is crashing with this error:

```
const member = message.guild.member(user);
                             ^         

TypeError: Cannot read property 'member' of null
```

I alrady tried to do `message.author.send('Hello World');` But it's the same problem...

I am declaring user and member in a separated file `'utiles.js'`:

```
const Discord = require('discord.js');
const Client = new Discord.Client();



module.exports ={
    getUtiles: function (message){
            const user = message.mentions.users.first();
            const member = message.guild.member(user);
            const args = message.content.trim().split(/ +/g);
            const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();
            const usrTag ='<@'+ member + '>'; //get the mentionned user tag
            
            this.user = user;
            this.member = member;
            this.args = args;
            this.usrTag = usrTag;
            
            return user, member, args, usrTag;
    }
}
```

Comment: Your error message indicates that the value of `message.guild` doesn't contain a method or property called `member()`, most likely because `message.guild` is null or undefined. We can't see where you've created that variable in the code you've shown.

Comment: @Alex Thank you for your comment, I added utiles.js in the question.

Comment: Found this snippet here: https://github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/frequently-asked-questions.md - you may need to change `message.guild.member(user)` to `message.guild.members.get(user)`.

Comment: Also, it looks like the API has totally changed recently, which will break old code. I don't know how recently you've started your bot, but this may help you: https://discordjs.guide/additional-info/changes-in-v12.html

Comment: @Alex The  link you sent me ( github.com/AnIdiotsGuide/discordjs-bot-guide/blob/master/…) is for the older version of discord.js. And I didn't find anything about a new way to send private messages in the guide. But thanks for the help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `const member = message.guild.member(user);` to `const member = message.member`, this code worked for me, so replace the  `if (command === 'rhelp') {` with `if (message.content.startsWith('!RHelp')){` to work your your case.

```
    if (command === 'rhelp') {
    let member = message.member
    member.send("Hello")
     message.reply('I just sent you a DM');
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you are doing things in a DM, there is no `message.guild` and thus there is no member function. You would need to check if the message.guild is null or not and then act accordingly. It's unclear how / when the `getUtiles` function is run so the specific solution is up to you in that regard.